Ubuntu 24.04 LTS VPN Connections in Network Manager
I've done a profile change on my laptop to have domain logins.  In doing so, I copied all config files in my home directory to a temp location, and then into the new home directory, obviously doing a chown to the new user id.  After login, I noticed all of my NetworkManager VPN connections had disappeared.  I can still see all of the .nmconnection files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/system-connections.  I have updated the permissions in each of these files, and restarted NetworkManager, but nothing seems to bring them back in to the GUI.  I have also noticed, that new VPN connections I create don't save into the same directory and don't show up anywhere on the root drive as a .nmconnection file.
Is there another location I should be looking for the VPN configuration file since the Ubuntu upgrade, or does the fact that it is now a domain login have effect, are the VPN profiles stored somewhere completely different?
Thanks in advance.

check in /etc/netplan, I found my "GUI profiles" in there.

Thanks Ovski, that is indeed where they are.  Is there an easy way to convert the old Network Manager (.nmconnection) files to the YAML format used by Netplan?

@GarrickCobcroft yes, after placing the .nmconnection files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections run sudo dpkg-reconfigure network-manager which re-runs the migration to /etc/netplan YAML files.
